# How to suspend active ssh connection

Tags: ssh, bash

How do I suspend an ssh connection. Control-Z suspend remote process. I use OpenSSH client and bash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use escape character. The escape character must always follow a newline. ~^Z(~ Ctrl+Z) - background ssh.

Supported escapes:

```
 ~.      Disconnect.
 ~^Z     Background ssh.
 ~#      List forwarded connections.
 ~&      Background ssh at logout when waiting for forwarded connection / X11 sessions to terminate.
 ~?      Display a list of escape characters.
 ~B      Send a BREAK to the remote system (only useful for SSH protocol version 2 and if the peer supports it).
 ~C      Open command line.  Currently this allows the addition of port forwardings using the -L, -R and -D options (see above).  It also allows the cancellation of existing remote port-forwardings using -KR[bind_address:]port.  !command allows the user to execute a local command if the PermitLocalCommand option is enabled in ssh_config(5).  Basic help is available, using the -h option.
 ~R      Request rekeying of the connection (only useful for SSH protocol version 2 and if the peer supports it).
```

Answer (score 2):

you can suspend 'remote' process using the same way like with Ctrl+Z, but you need to do it manually:

`kill -SIGSTOP $session_pid`

If you want to "preserve" the connection instead, you might want to use screen, tmux or similar software.